# How to code in C++ mutiple return values to main from mutiple modules and display each modules totals?

Tags: c++, arrays

I must write a program where the user can choose to practice with topic addition or topic multiplication that starts with a self-driven menu.
It must keep track of questions answered right, wrong and the number of questioned asked.
Which my current program is doing within each module(topic). Example Addition keeps track of the questions while the user is practicing Addition only and Multiplication does the same.
However, they are not being feedback to main, so they are not being added or displayed before the user can select another topic to practice or to exit the program.
Currently it is only to keeping track of the question (right /wrong/ total of questions) for each module (topic).
My goal is for the values to be passed to main and display the total number (right /wrong/ total of questions) before the user exits the program, but at the same time I must display the number of question in the Additional Topic and the Multiplication topic and provide a total.

Example Table of Addition, Multiplication and Totals ?

[image]

This is the code I have to start with. Can someone help me in how to code to return values of the (right /wrong/ total of questions) of the two topics and accomplish to display something like the table information.

```
******************************************************************************* /
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h> /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h> /* time */
#include <string> // String managment funtions.
#include <iostream> // For input and output
#include <cmath> // For math functions.
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Implementing menu driven programs.
// Function Prototypes.
int menu();
void sums();
void products();

int main()

{
    srand(time(0));

    int option;
    do {
        option = menu();
        switch (option) {
        case 1: {
            sums();
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            products();
            break;
        }

        default:
            cout << "Program exit" << endl;
        }
    } while (option != 6);
    return 0;
}

int menu()
{
    cout << "Please select an option" << endl;
    cout << "1) Practice with Addition " << endl;
    cout << "2) Pratice with Multiplication " << endl;
    cout << "3) Exit the program " << endl;
    int option;
    cin >> option;
    return option;
}
void sums()
{

    string keepgoing;
    unsigned int quantity_total_questions = 0U;
    unsigned int quantity_wrong_answers = 0U;
    unsigned int quantity_correct_answers = 0U;

    do {
        const int minValue = 10;
        const int maxValue = 99;

        int y = (rand() % (maxValue - minValue + 1)) + minValue;
        // cout<< " the random number is y "<< y << endl;
        int x = (rand() % (maxValue - minValue + 1)) + minValue;
        // cout<< " the random number is x "<< x << endl;

        cout << "What is " << x << " + " << y << " =" << endl;
        int answer;
        cin >> answer;

        if (answer == (x + y)) {
            cout << "Great!! You are really smart!!" << endl;
            ++quantity_correct_answers;
            ++quantity_total_questions;
        }

        else {
            cout << "Oh Sorry Try Again." << endl;
            ++quantity_wrong_answers;
            ++quantity_total_questions;
        }
        cout << "Right: " << quantity_correct_answers;
        cout << " Wrong: " << quantity_wrong_answers;
        cout << " Total Questions: " << quantity_total_questions << endl;

        cout << "Do you want to play again? [enter y for yes or n for no]" << endl;
        cin >> keepgoing;

    } while (keepgoing == "y");
}

void products()
{
    {

        string keepgoing;
        unsigned int quantity_total_questions = 0U;
        unsigned int quantity_wrong_answers = 0U;
        unsigned int quantity_correct_answers = 0U;

        do {
            const int minValueOne = 0;
            const int maxValueOne = 9;

            const int minValueTwo = 10;
            const int maxValueTwo = 99;

            int y = (rand() % (maxValueOne - minValueOne + 1)) + minValueOne;
            // cout<< " the random number is y "<< y << endl;

            int x = (rand() % (maxValueTwo - minValueTwo + 1)) + minValueTwo;
            // cout<< " the random number is x "<< x << endl;

            cout << " What is " << x << " x " << y << " =" << endl;
            int answer;
            cin >> answer;

            if (answer == (x * y)) {
                cout << "Great!! You are really smart!!" << endl;
                ++quantity_correct_answers;
                ++quantity_total_questions;
            }

            else {
                cout << "Oh Sorry Try Again." << endl;
                ++quantity_wrong_answers;
                ++quantity_total_questions;
            }
            cout << "Right: " << quantity_correct_answers;
            cout << " Wrong: " << quantity_wrong_answers;
            cout << " Total Questions: " << quantity_total_questions << endl;

            cout << "Do you want to play again? [enter y for yes or n for no]" << endl;
            cin >> keepgoing;

        } while (keepgoing == "y");
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer to your C++ textbook on references (which you could pass in as arguments to `sums` and `products`) OR the `std::tuple` data structure, which bundles a fixed number of values. If you did not learn about these techniques yet, I guess you were supposed to use global variables?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a structure that contains the number of total answers and number of correct answers—the incorrect ones can be inferred—and then pass a reference to an instance of the structure to the respective `sums()` and `products()` functions.

Those functions can then populate the structure elements and when they return, your main function can read them out, knowing exactly how many questions were asked, how many were answered, or whatever other information you want to record and retrieve.